# How to color LineString segments differently in Mapbox GL JS animations

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm making an animation that shows where wolves go, based on some historical GPS-collar data I've got.
The code is based on this Mapbox example:
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/

I would like to color the line segments based on whether it was daytime or nighttime, blue for night and red for daytime. Like this:

[image]

In time period 1, the wolf moves east-northeast; it's nighttime, so the line segment is blue. In time period 2, the wolf moves northeast; it's daytime, so the line segment is red. In time period 3, the wolf moves east-northeast again; it's nighttime, so the line segment is blue again.

But I can't seem to get the different coloring to work. I've got some toy/example data:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [ { "type": "Feature", "geometry": {
"type": "LineString", "coordinates" : [[-112.191833, 57.073668],
[-112.181833, 57.083668],
[-112.181833, 57.073668],
[-112.201833, 57.075668]]} } ], 
"properties": {"daytime" : [0, 1, 1, 0] }}
```

There are 4 time periods and the middle two are daytime (set to 1).

Here's my code. (You'll need to paste in your mapbox key for it to work):

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'INSERT YOUR MAPBOX KEY HERE';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
 container: 'map',
 style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
 zoom: 0
});

map.on('load', function() {
 // We use D3 to fetch the JSON here to parse and use it separately
 // from GL JS's use in the added source. You can use any request method 
 // that you want.
 d3.json(
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pete-rodrigue/wolves_of_alberta/data_store/wolves_geojson_example.geojson?token=ACEMB42EH5NKZSF24MHPQSS6JFTMU",
  function(err, data) {
   if (err) throw err;
   
   // save full coordinate list for later
   var coordinates = data.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
   // save 1's and 0's for later
   var daynight = data.properties.daytime  
   
   // start by showing just the first coordinate
   data.features[0].geometry.coordinates = [coordinates[0]];
   // THIS NEXT LINE IS ONE PART OF MY FAILED APPROACH:
   data.properties.daytime = ['blue'];   //  set initial color value to blue
   
   // add it to the map
   map.addSource('trace', { type: 'geojson', data: data });
   map.addLayer({
    'id': 'trace',
    'type': 'line',
    'source': 'trace',
    'paint': {
     // THIS WILL WORK FINE
     'line-color': 'orange',   
     // 'line-color': ['to-string', ['get', 'daytime']], //  DOES NOT WORK
     'line-width': 8
    },
    layout: {'line-cap': 'round', 'line-join': 'round'}
   });
   
   // setup the viewport
   map.jumpTo({ 'center': coordinates[0], 'zoom': 13 });
   map.setPitch(30);
   
   // on a regular basis, add more coords from the saved list to update map
   var i = 0;
   var timer = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (i < coordinates.length) {
     data.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push(
      coordinates[i]
     );
     
     // if it's daytime, append blue; if it's nighttime, append red
     if (daynight[i] == 0) {
      data.properties.daytime.push(['blue']);
     } else {data.properties.daytime.push(['red']);}
    
    map.getSource('trace').setData(data);
    map.panTo(coordinates[i]);
    i++;
   } else {
    window.clearInterval(timer);
   }
  }, 150);
 }
);
});
```

```css
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Wolves GPS collar example data</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.7.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main_css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='main_js.js'></script>
</body>
```

Also here:
https://codepen.io/pete-rodrigue/pen/XWbJOpK

I've commented out the part that wasn't working and left a note.

Basically, I'm trying to do this:

```
'line-color': ['to-string', ['get', 'daytime']]
```

in the `paint` part of `map.addLayer()`, where the `daytime` property is an array of strings that say 'blue' or 'red', which I push new elements onto as the animation progresses--that's this part of the code:

```
if (daynight[i] == 0) {
   data.properties.daytime.push(['blue']);  // if it's daytime, append blue
 } else {
   data.properties.daytime.push(['red']);  // if it's nighttime, append red
 }
```

I'm sure there's an obvious reason why this doesn't work. But I'm new at this and can't fathom it.

Any help and explanation of the fundamentals would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify:

```
'line-color': ['to-string', ['get', 'daytime']]
```

in the `'trace'` layer with `Map#addLayer`, the map renderer is being told to use `'[0, 1, 1, 0]'` (in the case of the example data you provided) as the color for the lines in the `source` with id `'trace'`. It does not wait for you to set up the timer, and even if it did, you'd likely run into some problems with JavaScript's asynchronicity. As noted in Mapbox's [style specification](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-line-line-color), `'line-color'` expects a [`color`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/types/#color) in the form of HTML-style hex values, RGB, RGBA, HSL, or HSLA, so you are likely running into errors since a stringified array is none of those forms.

Instead, I'd recommend breaking up each time period into its own `LineString` where the `'line-color'` is specified by its corresponding value in the original color array, and adding these `LineString`s to the map as separate layers. You can then create the animation effect by setting up some intervals to specify the order in which the layers should be added and animated as done in the [live update feature example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-update-feature/).

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a try.